# Units from :urn/metadata/:guid/properties

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I have for some time been hoping that Autodesk would correct the units of translated IFC files from BIM360, but seems that will not be the case anytime soon. Therefore I have started looking into converting values myself. The problem is however the precision of the data I get from the api calls.

If I find some data on BIM360 and look at a value in feet it might look like:
Dimensions > Height = 2.8707349081364826
2.8707349081364826 * 304,8 = 875 mm

If I find the same data through :urn/metadata/:guid/properties (https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/) The data is instead:
Dimensions > Height = 2.871 ft
2.871 * 304,8 = 875.0808 mm

So my question is now, is there a way to receive properties pre-converted, or receive the actual values instead of these pre-processed values?

Hope someone are able to come with a suggestion that could give me a better result.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you share a non-confidential model demonstrating this issue and point out which element has this problem? I got no luck reproducing this problem on rac_basic_sample_project.rvt at my side. If the model cannot be posted publicly, please send it to forge[DOT]help[AT]autodesk[DOT]com. **Note. Please remove any confidential information and personal data from anything you want to share with us.**

Comment: Notice that I wrote about an IFC file, those are my main issue atm and that I have been in contact with BIm360 support about several times. But I can defiantly send you an IFC file that shows my issue.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I mean that I cannot reproduce this problem on the IFC model converted from rac_basic_sample_project.rvt at my side. Yes, if you could share a model demonstrating this issue with us, it would be nice for our investigation.

Comment: I sent an email to you. Might be a question of original files being in imperial vs metric. But what I have found after approximately June 20th 2019 is that all IFC's (no matter native software) turn from the original metric to imperial on upload to BIM360.

Comment: Yes, BIM360 Docs is using Revit based IFC translation pipeline now, so the model length units will become imperial. Thank you for the file. I will reply to you via the Forge customer support system